# In Google Drive, is there a way to search files located in a particular folder?

Tags: google-drive

In Google Drive, is there a way to search only the contents of files within a particular folder (instead of files within the entire drive, as is the default)?

Comment: It doesn't look that way, no. You can filter by owner, date, sharing status; but not by folder.

Comment: Try the `in:folder_name` operator (e.g. `in:folder_name search_term`. Found [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/o9mTqeRCIw4).

Comment: @Alex yes, why not add that as an answer, it's what I would have suggested :)

Comment: @OnenOnlyWalter Because I haven’t tested it myself, I just took it from there, but if the OP confirms that it works, I will add it as an answer.

Comment: @Alex Sorry, I just tried what you said, but apparently it doesn't work (no results even when I know the file is there).

Comment: There's always the really boring way of having your Google Drive synced to your desktop computer (e.g. a Mac), and use your OS's searching capability (e.g. Spotlight) to search a specific subfolder.

Comment: @Alex it unfortunately doesn't work for me, either.  Like Hydra (above), I get 0 results for search terms using the "in:folder" syntax where I know there should be results. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: What's funny is that if I search and Google Docs says "documents found in Trash" and I click "view" it shows me "<docname>  in:Trash" but if I do that search....it returns NO RESULTS. Geesh... Google. WTF?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Alex Seems to me that `in:xxx` means in a particular Team Drive.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Google just announced that now they included a the [search within folder](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2018/01/search-within-folder-in-google-drive.html) feature.

From the above link:

> You can now search for content in a specific folder in Google Drive. Select the drop-down in the search bar and choose the folder you want from the Location menu, or right-click on a folder and search within that folder. Only folders that are within your My Drive or within Team Drives can be searched; if you have a folder that is shared with you, first add the folder to your My Drive.

Comment: This does not work. Following these instructions just opens the folder, rather than searching within it.

Comment: Please read the instructions again and follow them carefully. If you still need help, post a new question.

Answer (score 9):

Simply star the folders or particular files that you wish to search and then search "is:starred".  Unstar them once you want to search something else.  It's a little impractical, but it's what I do to search my journal articles, 1000s of which I've stored on my Drive.

Answer (score 9):

As of the date of this post, Google Drive does ***not*** support searching within a specific folder. However, the new Docs, Sheets, and Slides home screens do have a way to let you do this via the *File Picker* search interface:

- Go to: https://docs.google.com
- Click the File Picker folder icon on the right side of screen.
- Navigate to the specific folder that you want to search.
- Now put your query term in the file picker's search box and hit 'Enter'
  (Or click the 'Search for all items containing ')

Your search results will only come from the folder you selected.

Note: you can still filter by file type in the *File Picker* search bar by clicking the drop down arrow.

Comment: why doesn't drive search show you the containing folder name?

Comment: This is a rather convoluted way of doing it and ignores people who mostly use drive.google.com. Obviously the view count of this page shows that missing folder searching in their interface was very short sighted on Google's part. Sigh.

Comment: @deltaray I'm guessing somewhere at Google there is some risk analysis regarding features, e.g., cost of implementing+maintaining a feature vs benefit in data acquisition.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this doesn't search subfolders nor does it allow wildcards / requires full keyword. For illustrations and more details: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-search-for-files-within-a-folder-in-Google-Drive/answer/David-Debard?srid=ptsW

Comment: @SuperUberDuper This can (now) be seen by, after entering your search query in drive search, hitting enter, selecting the file below the search bar and viewing the details of the file (icon that looks like an "i", then choose the details tab (as opposed to the activity tab)). If the file has a parent (location) it will be listed there next to the folder icon.

Answer (score 3):

A time-consuming work around, which isn't so painful if there are just a few folders you want to search, is to share those folders with other Google accounts, and then include `to: thatgoogleaccount@example.com` in your search.

The script in user165768's answer also works. It asks you to share a scary bunch of permissions, so you may want to look at the code at https://github.com/ljv5555/drive-folder-search/tree/gh-pages/app to reassure yourself, and possibly make your own copy.

Answer (score 2):

I have written a simple Python script that can tag your files with folder, after which you can easily search by folder just by typing `folder:folder_name` or `folder:absolute_path`. You can get my code from here: https://github.com/songxf/drive-search-by-folder

Comment: so, it basically adds the folder path into description, pre appended by "SBFTK:folder:", and replaces it for when you move files around and run again, right? not too shabby! but what is sbftk?

Comment: @cregox My guess: `sbftk` is _search by folder something something_, maybe _search by folder tag something_.

Answer (score 2):

One solution: [gdrive](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive), which is a CLI for Google Drive.

To find items in a given folder, you use

```
gdrive list -q "'folderID' in parents"
```

To get the folderID, navigate to the folder in GDrive, then from the URL copy the ID, e.g., if I go to my folder "Pictures" the URL is
`https://drive.google.com/drive/u/8/folders/0B1FVU07aR9pFcDhFbUdkdhF9Oam8`

So the `folderID` is `0B1FVU07aR9pFcDhFbUdkdhF9Oam8`

`gdrive` allows you to use [all the search capabilities of the API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters) which are far more robust than the GUI.

However, this doesn't seem to be recursive, i.e., it only finds direct children of the given folder, not anything deeper.

**What's interesting, and worth exploring,** is that if I use a folderID and search from the GUI like `"in:0B1FVU07aR9pFcDhFbUdkdhF9Oam8"` then Google Drive shows the correct name of the folder almost like a filter in the GUI!

[image]

But it does NOT really work; I cannot find anything in the folder, and the GUI shows this error at the bottom of the screen:

[image]

Maybe someone can figure out a way to get this to work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like clicking through the folder selector in the `Location` drop-down, you can use the `parent:` search operator in the Search box with the Folder ID.

For example, if `f0LdEr-1D_abcdefghijklmnop` is the folder ID you see in the address bar when you open the folder, add `parent:f0LdEr-1D_abcdefghijklmnop` to the search box.

[image: Screenshot of folder ID in URL being copied to the search box next to "parent:" operator]

When you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `parent:f0LdEr-1D_abcdefghijklmnop` will disappear from the Search box, but it will still be visible in the URL. Right below the search box, you will see "Searching in `Foldername ✖`" (where `Foldername` is the name of the folder).

[image: Screenshot of "parent:" search operator in URL, but not in search box, with a circle around "Searching in Foldername"]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is such a feature available in Google Drive yet, but you can do a workaround.

If you do not intend to search for files recursively, simply just open the folder you want to search in and use the browser function (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) to search the name of your desired file.

Of course using this method you can't search within the file itself for text matches.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I want to search content within files, not just filenames.  I'm also looking to be able to recursively search within a folder (including subfolders). Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Answer (score 1):

There is another workaround that does *not* require any third party app or extension.

- Remove your folder (in which you wanna search something)
- Search with **is:trashed** filter. For example: `is:trashed query_string`
- Restore your folder back

Comment: For me, this only finds FOLDERS that are trashed, but not anything WITHIN those folders.

Answer (score 1):

Search within a folder [is now available](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2018/01/search-within-folder-in-google-drive.html) as of January 2018.

You can right-click on a folder name and Select  `Search within folder_name`
and it'll let you do so from the search bar of Google drive.

You can right-click on a folder from:

- Left navigation panel
- Folders inside My Folder
- Upper navigation helper
- Folder from 'Shared with me'
- Second level folders from one of your synced 'Computers'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for text inside the files, you could search your drive for the text, then use (Ctrl+F) to search for the folder name. A little messy, though, and again, not recursive!

Answer (score 0):

I have had very inconsistent success with:

```
in:<foldername>
```

This is somewhat inconsistent though.

This is how Google lets you search your Trash:      e.g.  `before:2013-06-01 in:Trash`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution – if you have a [G Suite](https://gsuite.google.com) account – is to use a [Team Drive](https://gsuite.google.com/learning-center/products/drive/get-started-team-drive). You can create a new Team Drive, not share it with anyone, and move folders into it. Then you can narrow your search to only the Team Drive.

[image]